# Write data frame with newline and tab to file

Tags: r

I am trying to write the following data frame in a file as it appears below (i.e. keeping the '\t' and '\n' as plain text).

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = quote("A\tB"), Col2=quote("C\nD"))
df
  Col1 Col2
1 A\tB C\nD
```

Doing `write.table(df, "my_file.tab", quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=F)` produces a file containing the following:

```
Col1    Col2
A   B   C
D
```

instead of:

```
Col1    Col2
A\tB    C\nD
```

or, if not possible without unquoting:

```
Col1    Col2
"A\tB"  "C\nD"
```

Comment: Do you really have `row,names` (comma), or is it really `row.names` (period)?

Comment: I don't know how any field/column formatted file can embed tabs and newlines without quoting ... and even there, multi-line (with embedded newlines) is often complicated.

Comment: Are you able to embed the literal string `\\n` (not a newline but can be clearly resolved to it)? Are you constrained to tab-delimited, or are there other formats you can use? What other clients need to be supported?

Comment: @r2evans Please see my edit. The delimiter can be anything. The client would be a basic text editor.

Comment: You can't get `\n` in a basic text editor, that'll be read as a newline and shown as such. If you want to see the literal `\t` and `\n` in the text editor (as in your last code block above), then they need to be `\\t` and `\\n` in ascii, and not true tab/newline characters.